# Why should have I to use Satis if i can specify private repos in composer.json?

Tags: composer-php, satis

I'm developing some libraries i frequently use across more than one project and i use GIT to version them.

Now, i'd like to use them through Composer.

Here comes my question: Composer makes me able to specify some private repositories from which i can pull source code to include in my apps (https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#using-private-repositories).

Then, i found Satis: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#satis

**Now, i don't well understand the differences between the two and which advantages i can have using Satis instead of using the private repositories through the Composer capabilities.**

**Should i really have to setup a Setis server? Which advantages does it bring to me?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, `Composer` looks for dependencies from your `composer.json` on special public package repository named [Packagist](https://packagist.org/).
`Packagist` stores each added repository location and its dependencies.
When you run `composer install`, `Composer` asks `Packagist` for dependencies and their locations and then downloads them.

But when you have a really big project with a lot of dependencies or(and) you are building your project rather frequently, then you can soon run into two problems.

The first and the main problem is **speed**. If you don't have wide internet connection, building your app simultaneously by all the members of your team can take **plenty of time**.

The second problem is that public repository hosting services like `Github` usually have [limits](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting) for api requests.

You can solve both these problems [setting up](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-a-local-mirror-for-composer-packages-with-satis--net-36726) a mirror of `Packagist` with `Satis` in your local infrastructure. In this case `Composer` won't go to `Packagist` for your dependencies, but ask your `Satis` server for them.

`Packagist` is a public service, but sometimes you want to add your another private repository as a dependency. You can add a special entry to your `composer.json` to make `Composer` download this package from another location.
And if you want, you can also make `Satis` to mirror your private repositories as it does with public ones.